# I want to update the client validation message of required validator in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-validation

I need have textbox in MVC.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "inp span15", @onkeydown = "javascript:FixMyInitialPaxName(this);", @onkeyup = "javascript:FixMyInitialPaxName(this);", @onblur = "javascript:FixMyInitialPaxName(this);", @onchange = "FixMyInitialPaxName(this)" })
```

Now, here I want to update the client validation message of required validator in mvc3.
Like I have three Textbox
TravelerName1 
TravelerName2 
TravelerName3

Now if the user not fill any textbox then message should be like 
"Please, fill the TravelerName #1",
"Please, fill the TravelerName #2" 
"Please, fill the TravelerName #3"

**it should get fire at client side and default error message get fire.**

Please, Help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jquery. Check with firebug the validation message generated. Then change the message in the `onclick()` event for submit button, by explicitly checking the desired condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the error message in `Data Annotations` as follows,

```
public class ViewModel
{
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Your Custom Message")]
[Display(Name = "Display Name")]
public int PropName { get; set; }

.....

}
```

Comment: I think OP is asking about changing this error message at client side.